# How to calculate the depth of a node in a pre-order tree array?

Tags: algorithm, tree, traversal

For example, a tree

```
             2
           /   \
          1     3
         / \   / \
       null n n   null
```

is stored as an array in pre-order: [2, 1, null, null, 3, null, null]. How do you calculate the depth of a node? or how to convert pre-order to depth-first?

Comment: see [here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/full-and-complete-binary-tree-from-given-preorder-and-postorder-traversals/)

Comment: If this is a binary tree, you just need to traverse the array. An element's left and right childrens' indices can be determined from the element's index in the array.

Answer (score 1):

Given just the pre-order traversal, that is impossible. Taking your example:

> [2, 1, null, null, 3, null, null]

there are several possible solutions to reconstruct a tree. Here are two:

```
         2
       /   \
      1     3
     / \   / \
   null n n   null

         2
       /   \
      1     3
     /     / \
   null   n   null
   /
 null
```

To reconstruct the tree you will need post-order aswell. Then you can follow the next link with the solution: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/full-and-complete-binary-tree-from-given-preorder-and-postorder-traversals/